Unable to Upload Logo for App Review on Meta/Facebook
I'm currently facing an issue where I can't submit my app for review on Meta/Facebook because it won't let me upload a logo. Every time I try, I get the message:
I've ensured that the type and size of the logo are correct, but despite trying to refresh the page and reopen the browser multiple times, the problem still persists.
Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!
